# Google Maps V3 + multiple Fusion Table layers = inconsistent markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api, google-fusion-tables

One of my colleagues is working on a map for a news story and is having some difficulty getting the markers to consistently show up. Changing the order in which the layers instantiate is causing significant variance in which markers are actually visible:

Compare: http://jsfiddle.net/aendrew/gTgHm/3/

...With: http://jsfiddle.net/aendrew/hLVzM/1/

[image: Version 1]

[image: Version 2]

For an obvious example, look to the right of the label for Glasgow — there are two green markers in the first version, three green in the second.

Is there some query limit I'm hitting with the Fusion Tables?

Note that each layer has **less than 100 markers.**

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known as *Too many markers*.
See this article: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers for possible solutions. They list a few.

Comment: It isn't TMM — please reread the question. Each layer has less than 100 markers, and they're already in a Fusion Table (one of the solutions listed in that article).

Comment: TMM is not an absolute figure though, it's relative to the zoom level and viewport. Have you tried to explicitly load one layer and only load teh next when one's finished and is rendered?